# How to display the GridView in the specific area at run time in the design page

Tags: asp.net

I want to Display the **Grid view** in a specific place at **run time** in my design page

Is there any solutions for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Grid view dynamically as follows

```
 GridView grid=new GridView();
 grid.ID = "";
 grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 grid.AllowPaging = true;
 grid.EnableViewState = true;
 grid.PageSize = 10;
```

Now you can add different columns to this grid:

```
BoundField bounfield=new BoundField();
boundfield.dataField=value;
grid.column.add(boundfield);
```

Then add this grid to a specific place like div

```
  sampleDiv.Controls.Add(grid);
```

Comment: divid.controls.add(grid) : Couldnot add this code in .cs file , how to add this code @balagurunathan-marimuthu

Comment: I have edited the code.Add a div in the  aspx page with Id sampleDiv.Also give 'runat=server'to.You could add this code in .cs file